# Solr ECONNRESET during load tests with Node.js

Tags: node.js, solr

I tried to create some load on our Solr server by means of a simple Node.js script which executes requests in a bluebird-"Promise.map". When i drive this up to about 1000 "parallel" requests, solr starts to close connections and i get "ECONNRESET" errors in Node.js.

I'm supprised, since it would assume that solr (or better to say jetty) should be able the handle this amount of requests. I don't see any indication for errors in the Solr log.

1.) Should solr / jetty be able to handle this? 
2.) Would it be expected, that "ECONNRESET" get more frequent, if solr has to process multiple heavy queries? 
3.) If 1. and 2. shouldn't be an issue, are there any suggestions, why this happens?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which solr version are you using ?

Comment: I used 5.4.0 before and switched now to 6.3.0. I have the issue with both versions.

Comment: can you check what is the value of <Set name="maxThreads"> in your jetty.xml ?

Comment: maxThreads is set to 10000.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? Im coming across the same exact thing when trying to update my indexes via node http streams.